# Accept post request with iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to accept a post request from my twilio account to my application to get an xml response back. How do I respond to an incoming post request in iron router? I have read the docs and tried everything in there but I just get (Error: Not implemented on server yet). I have tried putting it on the server, on the client and in lib.:

#### Router (lib/router.coffee)

```
Router.route('/api/twilio/voice', where: 'server')
  .post -> console.log 'hey'
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Does it help if you call `this.response.end()` inside the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to having `this.subscribe` then `.wait()`s configured for both server and client. Look for `.wait` within your `Router` configuration scopes and **make sure** it only runs at the **client**.

Look at the code part where this happens at the `iron-controller` repo:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-controller/blob/devel/lib/controller_server.js

Also I think a better way to debug (instead of `console.log`) is to actually use `this.response`:

```
    Router.route('/api/twilio/voice', { where: server })
      .post(function() {
        this.response.end('hey');
    });
```

or even the classic format:

```
    Router.route('/api/twilio/voice', { where: server })
      .post(function(req, res, next) {
        res.end('hey');
    });
```

Edit: Issue filed [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-controller/issues/4) and PR [here](https://github.com/electricjesus/iron-controller/commit/581a8fff191ac2525656e5b957a97196aa942106).

Comment: I am using subscribe in waitOn functions for my routes. How do I avoid running into those errors without wrapping the routes in 'isClient'? The iron router guide states all routes should be defined on server and client.

Comment: If you define them both in the client and server, wrapping in `Meteor.isClient` is a compromise you must accept..unless the github PR I submitted gets accepted. The reasoning behind this is to make sure the server-side version is run first before the client. Although I've had no problems going against this recommendation by declaring client-only routes and server-only routes in `client/` and `server/` folders respectively.

Comment: Seems like the iron:router behavior changed! At 1.0.0 apps were required to have at least one server route defined and the devs encouraged to define all routes everywhere. See [#944](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/944)